# Validate for double type in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to checking if a valid double type number "##.##" is entered in a text box? so if there is a decimal entered once, don't let users enter it again.

Would regular expressions be the best way to do this?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: regular expressions would be the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking in terms of jQuery, there are many options out there. Most of them involves a regular expression check.

Matching against a valid number is easy enough with regular expressions, if your main concern is preventing further character insertions, read on.

All you need to do is the following.

1. You need a character map of integers to 'allow' the inputs.
2. Prevent all other inputs except keys that match the character map.
3. Further prevent the 'dot' insertion if there is already one.

I will assume you allow patterns that starts with a dot, as long as javascript parses it as if there is a leading zero, and many developers treat this as a short-hand.

Also with the jQuery tag, assumed that you are working with jQuery.

```
$("#Foo").keydown(function(e) {
    var c = e.keyCode
      , value = $(this).val();

    // Prevent insertion if the inserting character is
    // 1. a 'dot' but there is already one in the text box, or
    // 2. not numerics.
    if ( (c == 190 && value.indexOf('.') > -1) || c < 48 || c > 57 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a nice little solution, however there is actually a bug I'm afraid... It should be:

if ( (c == 190 && value.indexOf('.') > -1) || c < 48 || (c > 57 && c != 190) ) {

In order to allow dots to be inserted. c > 57 will prevent dots all on its own.
Additionally, this does not allow for backspace, which is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex like this

```
> "222.22".match(/^\d+.?\d*$/)
["222.22"]

> "222.22.2".match(/^\d+.?\d*$/)
null
```

You can also just try to convert it to Number e.g.

```
> isNaN(Number("22.2.2"))
true
```

Only problem or advantage with checking by converting to Number is that it will allow number like 1e6

```
> isNaN(Number("1e6"))
false
```

Comment: Blank strings are an issue with this approach as well.  isNaN(Number('')) === false because Number('') === 0.  I think it would be better to use isNaN(parseFloat(...)).  But, that said, this approach is a bit off since the OP wanted to prevent the user from entering characters such as a second decimal (.).

Answer (score 0):

If using HTML5 is an option, you can use a new input type called "pattern".

It works like this:

```
<input id="numberField" type="text" title="You need to provide a number in the form of 2 integer and 2 decimal digits" pattern="\d{2}\.\d{2}" />
```

Then, you can register an event to make the element uneditable when it loses focus, like this (using jQuery):

```
$("#numberField").blur(function() { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); });
```

Alternatively, if you just want to check if what the field contains is a number (any form), you can just check it like this:

```
$("#numberField").blur(function() {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    };
}​);​
```

[Check it out on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehhct/).

Comment: How do you make entering the two decimal digits optional and how do you check if dot or comma is used for decimal in specific region?